# "...the more engrained the lessons they learn become."

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does the following sentence mean?

> The younger and longer boys view porn, the more engrained the lessons
>   they learn become.

[The article](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-3080409/Perfect-son-admits-watching-explicit-internet-porn-child-warped-attitude-women-left-feeling-depressed-anxious-mentally-disturbed.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the article you linked:

> As Jonny says: ‘Porn brought me to the brink, triggering anxiety, depression and invasive sexual thoughts about every woman I set eyes on.'

According to the article you linked, those are "the lessons learned from viewing porn". Maybe a more clear word is "the effects".

A paraphrasing:

> As boys watch porn longer, and as they start younger, the effects of porn become more engrained.

Engrained means:

> Deeply impressed or instilled. ([source](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/engrained))

So, a boy that does not start very young, and does not watch porn very long has these lessons (effects of watching porn) engrained a little bit, but a boy that starts very young, and does watch porn for a long time has these lessons engrained very deeply.